# ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when trying to access localhost on ASP.NET Web App project

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

So I've been working on this webapp project in my desktop computer, but I had to transfer it to my laptop since I have gone on holiday. The code builds fine, but when I try to access the site (http://localhost:port) in Chrome I get an ERR_CONNECTION_RESET message. I've also tried with other browsers (*Firefox, Microsoft Edge, Opera*) and I get a similar message. I also created a New Project and tried to run it with the same result. IIS Express seems to run without problems. I tried running `netstat -ao` in the cmd to see if the port assigned to the URL was being used by something else. And it was being actually used by a process with the PID:4, which turned out to be *NT Kernel & System*.

**Things I've tried:**

- Self signing a certificate.
- Writing 127.0.0.1 in the URL instead of localhost
- Reinstalling IIS
- Deleting the config files to make IIS create new ones
- Modifying the `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:port:localhost"/>` removing the `localhost` part, leaving it like this: `<binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:port:" />`
- Changing the port in Project Properties => Web, doesn't matter which one I pick, PID:4 always uses it.
- Opening `RegEdit` and setting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\HTTP`'s `start` attribute from 3 to 4, presumably stopping HTTP from listening to ports. Once I did this and rebooted the PC, I tried to run the dummy project again (the one which was only the template), and this time I got an `unable to launch the iis express web server`. I tried to work around it by reinstalling IIS and modifying the config, but it didn't work. At last, I decided to leave the 'start' attribute with value 3, and return to the `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` since I wasn't sure it had been a step forwards or backwards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds to me like you might not have the right IIS settings installed. Take a look in your windows features. Make sure you have support for the right version on ASP.NET turned on

[Here are the settings I'm currently using for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa2ff.png)

Comment: Should I leave the `start`attribute in 4 or in 3?

Comment: I'd set it back to whichever gave you the original error. "unable to launch iis express web server" sounds like an error we don't really want to have to fix

Comment: Ok, after rebooting once for the settings, then again because I forgot to set `start`in 3, I got a few more errors which I managed by myself. But the important thing is that now it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue open command prompt in Admin mode and go to below location:
cd

Run the below command at command prompt, after replacing 44353 with the port no. of your web application:
IisExpressAdminCmd.exe setupsslUrl -url:https://localhost:44353/ -UseSelfSigned

Rerun the web application from Visual Studio.

[image: Command Prompt]

[image: Web Application]